# images not taking up columns properly using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't see what's wrong. On small displays and higher each image should take 4 and only XS displays each image should take up 12 columns each which means each image takes up a new line each time but it's not doing that.

```
<div id="homenav" class="container">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="thumbnail pmbutton">
                <img src="images/matchingpairs.jpg" alt="Pair Match">
                <p>Pair Match</p>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="thumbnail ssbutton">
                <img src="images/shapes.jpg" alt="Super Shapes">
                <p>Super Shapes</p>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="thumbnail ccbutton">
                <img src="images/counting.jpg" alt="Cool Counting">
                <p>Cool Counting</p>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on the image dimensions

Comment: so what if I have a max-width and max-height for my image. is there still a way to make each image appear on a new line

Comment: I think you need to set `display: block` to your images for `xs` resolution.

Comment: You can try this with your class `col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4` then add to css `.thumbnail{  width: 100%;  height: auto;}` Is that what you looking for?https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/3qd6ge5z/

Answer (score 0):

This should change your row size;

```
<div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
```

This should change your button size inside corresponding row;

```
<button type="button" class="thumbnail ssbutton col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
```

And this should change your image size inside corresponding button;

```
<img src="images/matchingpairs.jpg" alt="Super Shapes" class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4" />
```

Or you can create your own CSS class to resize images and give this class name as class attribute to each image.

I hope this helps.

Cagri